# Issues about Peer to peer concepts

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, transactions, ether, peers

Hy every one, I'm new in this world, and i'm trying to understand deeply how blockchain works. I'm little bit confused about the peer to peer concept. How many peers have Ethereum blockchain, according to the exemples of https://andersbrownworth.com/blockchain/coinbase ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[This site](https://ethernodes.org/) will give you an idea about the different implementations and statistics regarding each running nodes. (5765 at the moment)

Anyone can clone a repository and start a node, hence the number of peers can be varied. When the block is verified and broadcasted peers will get synced

Geth Clients with different versions are displayed [here](https://ethernodes.org/client/geth)

Comment: Link-only answers are of very limited value on the Stack Exchange network. Please consider adding the relevant parts to the answer itself.